# Redefinition of default argument: parameter 2

Tags: c++, class, sfml

Header file:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Paths
{
private:

public:
    Paths();

    string Image(string key, string extension = "png");
    string Font(string key, string extensino = "TTF");
};
```

CPP file:

```
#include "Paths.hpp"

Paths::Paths()
{

}

string Paths::Image(string key = "nullImage", string extension = "png")
{
    return "data/images/" + key + "." + extension;
}

string Paths::Font(string key = "NULLFONT", string extension = "TTF")
{
    return "data/fonts/" + key + "." + extension;
}
```

For my program, I want to facilitate the images, fonts (etc) paths.
For my 2 string voids, visual studio says: "Redefinition of default argument: parameter 2". Can anyone explain what this means and how I can fix my code?

Comment: "Redefinition of default argument: parameter 2." means that you define the default value more than once. Looking at your code, which has both defaults after a `=` twice, what is unclear?

Comment: Default values for the Font and Image methods should be only in the header file (.h). In the cpp, you need to remove the = "TTf", = "png" and so on... Default values should be defined only once; otherwise, you could define 2 different values and this would not make sense :-/

Comment: An alternate approach I sometimes see is making these a comment `string extension /*= "png"*/` in the cpp file so: `string Paths::Image(string key /*= "nullImage"*/, string extension /*= "png"*/)` but a negative to that is if these ever change in the header your comment may be out of sync.

Comment: Yes it means simply don't specify your default arguments in both your header and your main cpp file, remove ="png" and ="TTF" from your CPP file , but leave them in the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the default parameters multiple times. Do the following:

Header:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Paths
{
private:

public:
    Paths();

    string Image(string key, string extension = "png");
    string Font(string key, string extensino = "TTF");
};
```

Cpp:

```cpp
#include "Paths.hpp"

Paths::Paths()
{

}

string Paths::Image(string key, string extension)
{
    return "data/images/" + key + "." + extension;
}

string Paths::Font(string key, string extension)
{
    return "data/fonts/" + key + "." + extension;
}
```